# Modify Groovy sources from Gradle build before compiling

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a Groovy application that I build with Gradle. As usual I have defined the application version number/string in the `build.gradle` script.

Now I want to use that version string within the Groovy application, as hard-coded static piece of information. For example as a `final static` member in the main application class:

```
class MyApp {
    final static APP_VERSION = "0.1"
}
```

Since the version information comes from the `build.gradle` script, that Groovy class member above needs to be set by Gradle before the sources are compiled.

In other words: I need a Gradle task that allows me to set the value of a variable in the Groovy sources, before they are built by Gradle. I could for search for that value via regular expression and replace it in the Groovy source file, but that feels a bit clunky.

Any "best practice" ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: Does the class contain anything except the version? Is there some reason you can't write read it from a properties file?

Comment: @DylanBijnagte: I want to hard-code the version, but not read it from a file at runtime. And yes, the class does contain other code beside this version attribute.

Comment: If the file was minimal I would say template it, otherwise I think you may be stuck with the regex solution.

Comment: How bout creating a MyAppVersion class file with only this value in it.  MyApp references MyAppVersion but you wholesale replace MyAppVersion with the Gradle build before it compiles.  No need for regexp then.

Comment: @ToddWCrone: Hmmm... I guess that is a nice approach, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i can't give you final solution, but, i think, you should look at [AST Transformations](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/09/using-gradle-to-build-apply-ast-transformations.html)

Another option, if you pack the application in jar / war, - you can get a version of the application from the manifest file (but it will not work if you are starting app from IDE)

```
final static versin = MyApp.class.getPackage().getSpecificationVersion()
```

Comment: Well, with AST it might work. But it feels a bit like an overkill for this simple task, doesn't it?

Comment: I would have to agree.  AST Transformations for this is like lighting a cigarette with flamethrower.